# AJAX - help me understand that sequence of code

Tags: ajax, get, execution

```
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Can someone please help me understand the sequence of execution here?

xhttp.onreadystatechange is called with an IF waiting for the State ==4. But it's not 4 until xhttp.send() is triggered further down in the code. So once xhttp.send() triggers State=4, why is then onreadystatechange called again to execute the IF? I guess I'm looking at this as a top-down execution. I just don't get how/why onreadystatechange "waits" for State to change? Since its code has already been executed. Please explain as simply as possible and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) is an [event handler](http://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html), which means it triggers when a specific event fires.

> The XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange property contains the event
>   handler **to be called when the readystatechange event is fired**, that is
>   every time the readyState property of the XMLHttpRequest changes

(emphasis mine)